# Store inline HTML within variable in PHP

Tags: php, html, variables

I was wondering, mostly because I think I've seen it before somewhere, if it is possible to store HTML within a variable, something like the following (I know this makes no sense, it's just to clarify my question):

```
<? $var = ' ?>
text goes here
<? '; ?>
```

And then `$var` would equal `text goes here`

Comment: If possible you should avoid this. Embed PHP into HTML not vice versa.

Comment: "Embed PHP into HTML not vice versa." O RLY?

Comment: @Felix Kling: why would you recommend Embedding PHP into HTML and not vice versa?

Comment: @Nightwolf: Because creating endless HTML strings is error prone (e.g. escaping of quotes). You will most likely also loose syntax highlighting if you use an IDE. Granted, with heredoc it might not be that bad, but there is barely a reason to not write HTML the "normal" way and just `echo` the data where it should be. It is a better separation of logic and presentation.

Comment: @Felix Kling, what I want to use this for is for newsletter templates that require a php configuration for my system as well as a HTML template. I'd like these two to be included in the same php file without losing my HTML syntax coloring. I figured this was a great solution.

Comment: @Kokos: I didn't mean that it *always* bad. Using it for an email template is an ok use case imo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do that using output buffering. Have a look at the examples at [ob_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) and [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

```
<? ob_start(); ?>

All kinds of stuff, maybe some <?= "php"; ?> etc.

<? $var = ob_get_contents(); ?>
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for, heredoc solves my problem as well but leaves the code colored like php in Dreamweaver which was one of the reasons I wanted this.

Comment: One thing is also needed though, without `ob_end_clean();` the original HTML will still be outputted.

Comment: Or even you can just use ob_get_clean() instead of doing ob_get_contents() + ob_end_clean()

Answer (score 6):

You *may* be thinking of the [Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
<?php
$var = <<<EOD
text goes here
EOD;
?>
```

Comment: Note that this will generate the string `"\ttext goes here\n\t"`. Be careful of whitespace.

Comment: The trailing `EOD` should not be indented, it should be on the first column. Also, this way the text will contain spaces in front.

Comment: @Eric Good point. I edited out the tabs, though (thanks for your initial edit - I forgot) since the `EOD;` *must* (AFAIR) be at the start of the line.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev Yes, this was due to an edit collision :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this facebook blog post](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/xhp-a-new-way-to-write-php/294003943919) on XHP, a language that allows XML literals within PHP code.